# creating a performance tool for web based GUI

Tags: browser, automation, ui-testing, website-metrics

I want to create an automated performance metric gathering tool, to get various metrics for page load times for a flash based web application.  I am doing the web automation using a batch script, and then I want to collect the various metrics using browsermob-proxy (http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/), it exports the metrics in a HAR file.  I've never done this before so I was wondering if this approach is okay? What are the steps to using browswermob-proxy for windows (firefox).  There is no information about windows in the documentation, just linux.  I know I run the proxy from the /bin directory, then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had downloaded the copy from the browsermob zip from here..http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/  Unzip and refer the readme.md
The readme file in the browsemob zip, specifies the instructions to start the proxy server.  Once the server is started, you would need to specify the server port and machine ip in your firefox proxy settings (from options->advanced->network>settings.  Then trigger your urls on this browser.